# How can i improve my query speed in MongoDB, NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose

I have one collection who include some value coming from sensor. My collection look like this.

```
const MainSchema: Schema = new Schema(
  {
    deviceId: {
      type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
      required: true,
      ref: 'Device',
    },
    sensorId: {
      type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
      default: null,
      ref: 'Sensor',
    },
    value: {
      type: Number,
    },
    date: {
      type: Date,
    },
  },
  {
    versionKey: false,
  }
);
```

I want to get data from this collection with my endpoint. This collection should has more 300.000 documents. I want to get data from this collection with sensor data. (like name and desc. to "Sensor")

My Sensor Collection:

```
const Sensor: Schema = new Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      min: 3,
    },
    description: {
      type: String,
      default: null,
    },
    type: {
      type: String,
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
    versionKey: false,
  }
);
```

I use 2 method for get data from **MainSchema**. First approach is look like this (Include aggregate):

**startDate, endDate and _sensorId are passed by parameter for this functions.**

```
const data= await MainSchema.aggregate([
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: 'Sensor',
        localField: 'sensorId',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: 'sensorDetail',
      },
    },
    {
      $unwind: '$sensorDetail',
    },
    {
      $match: {
        $and: [
          { sensorId: new Types.ObjectId(_sensorId) },
          {
            date: {
              $gte: new Date(startDate),
              $lt: new Date(endDate),
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    },
    {
      $project: {
        sensorDetail: {
          name: 1,
          description: 1,
        },
        value: 1,
        date: 1,
      },
    },
    {
      $sort: {
        _id: 1,
      },
    },
  ]);
```

Second approach look like this (Include find and populate):

```
const data= await MainSchema.find({
    sensorId: _sensorId,
    date: {
      $gte: new Date(startDate),
      $lte: new Date(endDate),
    },
  })
    .lean()
    .sort({ date: 1 })
    .populate('sensorId', { name: 1, description: 1});
```

Execution time for same data set:

**First approach:** 25 - 30 second

**Second approach:** 11 - 15 second

So how can i get this data more faster. Which one is best practise?

And how can i do extras for improve the query speed?

Comment: I assume that no indices were created so far, is that correct? Are you sure that using mongodb as a database is the way to go in your case? There are several time based databases out there which are usually the best fit in order to store metrics (like sensor data).

Comment: I created index for my collections. Which database would you recommend for this case?

Comment: Can you gather the verbose explain plan (`.explain("allPlansExecution")` for this aggregation and include a link to it (maybe pastebin.com ?) in your question? Also, how often do your sensors capture data?

Comment: You can take a look at InfluxDB if you are looking for an open source alternative. It can handle things like data aggregation based on time events etc. for you. Additionally if you want you can integrate other open source software like grafana out of the box in order to display your data efficiently.

Comment: Thx for information. I will research it.

Answer (score 1):

#### Frist step

Create index for `sensorId` and `date` properties in the collection. You can do it by specifying `index: true` in your model:

```js
const MainSchema: Schema = new Schema(
  {
    deviceId: { type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: 'Device' },
    sensorId: { type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, default: null, ref: 'Sensor', index: true },
    value: { type: Number },
    date: { type: Date, index: true },
  },
  {
    versionKey: false,
  }
);
```

#### Second step

Aggregation queries can take leverage of indexes only if your `$match` stage is the first stage in the pipeline, so you should change the order of the items in your aggregation query:

```js
const data= await MainSchema.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        { sensorId: new Types.ObjectId(_sensorId) },
        {
          date: {
            $gte: new Date(startDate),
            $lt: new Date(endDate),
          },
        },
      },
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: 'Sensor',
        localField: 'sensorId',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: 'sensorDetail',
      },
    },
    {
      $unwind: '$sensorDetail',
    },
    {
      $project: {
        sensorDetail: {
          name: 1,
          description: 1,
        },
        value: 1,
        date: 1,
      },
    },
    {
      $sort: {
        _id: 1,
      },
    },
  ]);
```

Comment: I will use index prop, thanks for advice. So does query order important? And if i use index property with second approach will query speed increase?

Comment: In aggregation query, order is really important. If you add index and change the order so `$match` would be the first in the pipeline, query performance should increase a lot.

Comment: I tried ordered and unordered query and exec time doesn't change so much. Results are so similar. Is that normal?

Comment: What do you mean by ordered and unordered? Are you talking about sorting? This has nothing to the with sorting. You just have to put `$match` stage first in the aggregation pipeline so your query would leverage indexes. 

Also, are you sure that you have indexes? Did you added them to the schema model?

Comment: I added index. Ordered means put $match stage first, unordered means put $match stage third or more.

Comment: In your query, you specified `{ sensorId: new Types.ObjectId(_sensorId) },`. Are you fetching only one document or multiple documents?

Comment: I fetch multiple document. Almost over than 20000.

Comment: Oh I see. That is why it probably takes long. It's a lot of data to be transferred through the network. Do you need it all at once or you need only a portion of it? Maybe you can consider adding pagination?

Comment: I am going to use this data on chart. Is pagination approach work? I'm not sure.

Comment: If you need all the data then it does not make sense to do pagination.

Comment: Hmm I need all, by the way thanks a lot :)

Comment: There wasn't going to be nearly enough space for me to reply as a comment, so I expanded on @NeNaD's great answer above with some additional thoughts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74115837/20042973)

Answer (score 1):

Overall [@NeNaD's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74111756/20042973) touches on a lot of the important points. What I'm going to say in this one should be considered *in addition to* that other information.

##### Index

Just to clarify, the ideal index here would be a compound index of `{ sensorId: 1, date: 1 }`. This index follows the [ESR Guidance for index key ordering](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/equality-sort-range-rule/) and will provide the most efficient retrieval of the data according to the query predicates specified in the `$match` stage.

If the `index: true` annotation in Mongoose creates two separate single field indexes, then you should go manually create this index in the collection. MongoDB will only use one of those indexes to execute this query which will not be as efficient as using the compound index described above.

Also regarding the existing approach, what is the purpose of the trailing `$sort`?

If the application (a chart in this situation) does not need sorted results then you should remove this stage entirely. If the client does need sorted results then you should:

- Move the `$sort` stage earlier in the pipeline (behind the `$match`), and
- Test if including the sort field in the index improves performance.

As written, the `$sort` is currently a blocking operation which is going to prevent *any* results from being returned to the client until they are *all* processed. If you move the `$sort` stage up and can change it to sort on `date` (which probably makes sense for sensor data) the it should automatically use the compound index that we mentioned earlier to [provide the sort in a non-blocking manner](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/upcoming/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes).

##### Stage Ordering

Ordering of aggregation stages is important, both for semantic purposes as well as for performance reasons. The database itself will attempt to do various things (such as reordering stages) to improve performance so long as it does not logically change the result set in any way. Some of these optimizations are [described here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/). As these are version specific anyway, you can always take a look at the `explain` plan to get a better indication of what specific changes the database has applied. The fact that performance did not improve when you manually moved the `$match` to the beginning (which is [generally a best practice](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/#document-filters)) could suggest that the database was able to automatically do that on your behalf.

##### Schema

I'm a little curious about the schema itself.  Is there any reason that there are two separate collections here?

My guess is that this is mostly a play at 'normalization' to help reduce data duplication. That is mostly fine, unless you find yourself constantly performing `$lookup`s like this for most of your read operations. You could certainly consider testing what performance (and storage) looks like if you combine them.

Also for this particular operation, would it make sense to just issue two separate queries, one to get the measurements and one to get the sensor data (a single time)? The aggregation matches on `sensorId` and the value of that field is what is then used to match against the `_id` field from the other collection. Unless I'm doing the logic wrong, this should be the same data for each of the source documents.

##### Time Series Collections

Somewhat related to schema, have you looked into using [Time Series Collections](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/timeseries-collections/)?  I don't know what your specific goals or pain points are, but it seems that you may be working with IoT data. Time Series collections are purpose-built to help handle use cases like that. Might be worth looking into as they may help you achieve your goals with less hassle or overhead.

Comment: Great addition and perfect explanation! :D